# Curl Post data from a file .txt

Tags: bash

Hello this my bash script code i'm trying to post multi messages from a file
using post function

However when i try with this code its say:
 {"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006}

```
#!/bin/bash

SENDDATA="1.txt"
dir1=$SENDDATA
read dir1
curl -v \
-H "Authorization: " \
-H "User-Agent: myBotThing (http://some.url, v0.1)" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Referer: http://example.com" \
-X POST \
-d --data '{"content":".$SENDDATA."}' \
https://api.example.com/messages
```

I'm trying to change the posting Data '{"content":"blabla"}' \

With a file 1.txt of multi words messages.

I think something wrong!

Comment: you need to cat it to the variable `SENDDATA="cat 1.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

Your script does not read the data from the file. As @garlicFrancium suggested, you need to read the file somehow. You also have an extra `-d` in your arguments.

```sh
SENDDATA="1.txt"
curl -v \
        -H "Authorization: " \
        -H "User-Agent: myBotThing (http://some.url, v0.1)" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -H "Referer: http://example.com" \
        --data "{\"content\":\"$(cat "$SENDDATA")\"}" \
        https://api.example.com/messages
```

1.txt:

```
foo bar baz
```

Replacing the URL with `localhost:8080` and running `nc -l 8080`:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: */*
User-Agent: myBotThing (http://some.url, v0.1)
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://example.com
Content-Length: 25

{"content":"foo bar baz"}
```